# UITextfield limit with no special charecters ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` in which no special characters are allowed along with maximum of 20 charters length.

i am using following code to restrict the text field

```
NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
return (newLength > limitPassportNumber) ? NO : YES;
```

for stopping special charecters entry i have the following code.

```
NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS] invertedSet];
        NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
```

Now if i need to return both then only one will be executed.

Can someone please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the length. If it's too long, return `NO`. Otherwise check if the characters are valid.

Your code for checking for valid characters is very inefficient. Splitting and rejoining the whole string is not a good way to check to see if it contains any invalid characters.

The following code is a better way to handle your case:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSUInteger newLength = textField.text.length + string.length - range.length;
    if (newLength > limitPassportNumber) {
        return NO; // too long
    }

    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS] invertedSet];
    NSRange badRange = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:cs];

    return badRange.location == NSNotFound;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)isValidString:(NSString *)string{
    NSString *regex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z]*";
    NSPredicate *regTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];
    if ([regTest evaluateWithObject:string]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    if ([string length] == 0)
        return YES;
    if ([string length] > 0 && [string length] <=20) {
        NSString *newString = [textField text];
        newString = [newString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

        return [self isValidString:newString];
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Objective-C `BOOL` is either `YES` or `NO`. And it is much more efficient to check the length before validating the text against a regular expression. No sense evaluating the expensive predicate if the string is too long.

Comment: @rmaddy, Updated answer. Thanks for makes me correct. Really appreciate.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *str = @"[~!@#$%^&*()_+-]";

NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", str];

if([[str evaluateWithObject:textfield.text]== YES] && [textfield.text length]<20){

  // Do Something
}
else{

  //Textfield has a special character or the text is greater than 20
}
```

Comment: This is checking the wrong length. `emailTest` is never used.